# How to exclude inner webelement with css selectors?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have this css selector:

```
$("td.cv-table-panel-element")
```

that returns a list of elements as it appears in the screenshot below:

[image: List of elements returned by selector]

All these elements are columns of a table and each column content is different. The first element in that list contains a checkbox:

[image: Contents of the first element]

I want to exclude that element from the initial list.

Please note that merely ignoring the first element won't work here as this checkbox element is not consistent and does not always appear. Hence it needs to be excluded specifically by one of its inner classes.

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
$("td.cv-table-panel-element:not(.cv-checkbox)")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You will need to be very specific whether you're looking for a jQuery or CSS selector. jQuery has a number of proprietary selector features that are not compatible with most CSS selector implementations, such as Selenium (based on your use of the term "webelement" in your question), unless you're using a jQuery-specific driver.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Your observation is correct indeed, I do use it for Selenium automation. And in fact, I am lacking some understanding in regards to the differences between jQuery and CSS selectors. If you could point me to some sources where I can get my head around both these concepts I will be grateful! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pure CSS option:

```
td.cv-table-panel-element:not([align="center"])
```

This selector uses the [*`:not` functional notation*](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#negation) and an [*attribute selector*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).

Here's an example:

```css
/* td elements are red */
.cv-table-panel-element { background-color: red;}

/* td elements that DO NOT have the align="center" attribute are blue */
.cv-table-panel-element:not([align="center"]) { background-color: aqua; }

td { height: 100px; width: 100px; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cv-table-panel-element"></td>
    <td class="cv-table-panel-element"></td>
    <td class="cv-table-panel-element" align="center"></td>
    <td class="cv-table-panel-element"></td>
    <td class="cv-table-panel-element" align="center"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```